# Is there an error while writing the R record in the file " in function "ResultatdeMouvement"?

Tags: c

The Exercise is about filling Products names with their Stock capacity in file named `fichierProduit` and filling the movement (Import and Export) of this products in file named `fichierMouvment`. After filling these 2 files I create another file `fichierdeResultat` so I can write in it the new Stock Capacity. After doing some math the function related to this is `ResultatdeMouvement`, when displaying the Result it only displays the first product.

I tried to copy the name into the record "Resultat" (R) and then write it into the `fichierdeResultat` while displaying them in the function `AfficheDeProduitApresMouvement` it seems displaying only the first product name in file `fichierProduit`.

[image: result]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Produit{
char NomP[10] ;
int StockP;
};

struct Mouvement{
char MouveP[10];
int MouveAp;
int MouveV;
};
struct Resultat{
char NomPr[10];
int StockR;
};
//INSERTING NEW PRODUCTS LIST
void SaisirProduits(FILE* ficheierProduit){
struct Produit P;
ficheierProduit = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FProduit.dat","wb");
char rep;
do {
    fseek(ficheierProduit, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Saisir Nom de Produit: ");
    scanf("%9s",&P.NomP);
    printf("Saisir Capacite de Stock de Produit: ");
    scanf("%i",&P.StockP);
    fwrite (&P, sizeof(struct Produit), 1,ficheierProduit);
    if(fwrite!=0){
        printf("\n\Produit Ajoute avec succees !\n\n");
    }
    printf("Voulez Vouz Saisir un autre Produit (O,N): ");
    scanf(" %c",&rep);
    }while(toupper(rep)!='N');
fclose(ficheierProduit);
}
    //INSERTING NEW MOVEMENT LIST
void SaisirMouvement(FILE* fichierMouvment){
struct Mouvement M;
fichierMouvment = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FMouvment.dat","wb");
char rep;
do {
    fseek(fichierMouvment, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Saisir Nom de Produit a Ajouter un mouvement: ");
    scanf("%9s",&M.MouveP);
    printf("Saisir Capacite d'approvisionnement: ");
    scanf("%i",&M.MouveAp);
    printf("Saisir Nombre Vendu de ce Produit: ");
    scanf("%i",&M.MouveV);
    fwrite (&M, sizeof(struct Mouvement), 1,fichierMouvment);
    if(fwrite!=0){
        printf("\n\Mouvement Ajoute avec succees !\n\n");
    }
    printf("Voulez Vouz Saisir un autre Mouvement (O,N): ");
    scanf(" %c",&rep);
    }while(toupper(rep)!='N');
fclose(fichierMouvment);
}
//Function to verify if the Products Exist or not
int VerifierProduitExistouNon(char NomdeProduit[10],FILE* ficheierProduit){
struct Produit P;   ficheierProduit=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FProduit.dat","r+");
int found=0;
while(!feof(ficheierProduit)){
    fread(&P,sizeof(P),1,ficheierProduit);
    if(strcmp(P.NomP,NomdeProduit)==0){
        found=1;
        return found;
    }else if(feof(ficheierProduit) && found==0)
        return found;
}
fclose(ficheierProduit);
}
//Add New Products to the File
void AjouterNouveauProduit(FILE* fichierProduit){
struct Produit P;
fichierProduit=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FProduit.dat","ab+");
printf("Saisir Nom de Nouveau Produit: ");
scanf("%9s",&P.NomP);
if(VerifierProduitExistouNon(P.NomP,fichierProduit)!=0)
printf("\n\nProduit deja Exist Merci de Verifier !\n\n");
else{
printf("\nSaisir Capcite de Stock de Produit:  ");
scanf("%i",&P.StockP);

fwrite (&P, sizeof(struct Produit), 1,fichierProduit);
printf("\nSaisir de nouveau Produit avec Success ! \n");
}
fclose(fichierProduit);
}
//INSERTING NEW MOUVEMENT
void AjouterNouveauMouvement(FILE* fichierMouvment,FILE* fichierProduit){
struct Mouvement M;
fichierMouvment = fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FMouvment.dat","ab+");
printf("Saisir Nom de Produit a Verifier S'il exist: ");
scanf("%9s",&M.MouveP);
if(VerifierProduitExistouNon(M.MouveP,fichierProduit)!=0){
printf("\n\nProduit Exist Ajout de Nouveau Mouvement.....\n\n");
printf("\nSaisir Capcite d'approvisionnement de Ce Produit:  ");
scanf("%i",&M.MouveAp);
printf("\nSaisir Capcite de Vente de Ce Produit:  ");
scanf("%i",&M.MouveV);
fwrite (&M, sizeof(struct Mouvement), 1,fichierMouvment);
if(fwrite!=0){
printf("\nSaisir de nouveau Produit avec Success ! \n");
}
}else{
printf("\n\nCe Produit N existe pas dans le Stock Merci de Verifier ! \n\n");
}
fclose(fichierMouvment);
}  
//TRYING TO FILE THE RESULT FILE 
void ResultatdeMouvement(FILE* ficheierProduit,FILE* fichierMouvment,FILE* fichierResultat){
struct Produit P;
struct Mouvement M;
struct Resultat R;        ficheierProduit=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FProduit.dat","r+");
fichierMouvment=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FMouvment.dat","r+");
fichierResultat=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FResultat.dat","wb");
while(!feof(ficheierProduit)){
    fread(&P,sizeof(P),1,ficheierProduit);
    while(!feof(fichierMouvment)){
        fread(&M,sizeof(M),1,fichierMouvment);
        if(strcmp(P.NomP,M.MouveP)==0){
            strcpy(R.NomPr,P.NomP);
            R.StockR=P.StockP+(M.MouveAp-M.MouveV);
        }
    }
    fwrite(&R,sizeof(R),1,fichierResultat);
}
fclose(ficheierProduit);
fclose(fichierMouvment);
fclose(fichierResultat);
}
void AfficheDeMouvement(FILE* fichierdeMouvement){
struct Mouvement M;
fichierdeMouvement=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FMouvment.dat","r+");
while(fread(&M,sizeof(M),1,fichierdeMouvement)){
    printf("\n\nNom de Produit: %s | approvisionnement= %i | Vente= %i\n\n ",M.MouveP,M.MouveAp,M.MouveV);
}
fclose(fichierdeMouvement);
}
void AfficheDeProduitavantMouvement(FILE* fichierProduit){
struct Produit P;
fichierProduit=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FProduit.dat","r+");
while(fread(&P,sizeof(P),1,fichierProduit)){
    printf("\n\nNom de Produit: %s | Stock Valable = %i \n\n",P.NomP,P.StockP);
}
fclose(fichierProduit);
} 
void AfficheDeProduitApresMouvement(FILE* fichierResultat){
struct Resultat R;
fichierResultat=fopen("C:/Users/Ayoub/Desktop/EX5/EX5/FResultat.dat","r+");
while(fread(&R,sizeof(R),1,fichierResultat)){
    printf("\n\nNom de Produit: %s | Stock Valable Apres Mouvement: %i  \n",R.NomPr,R.StockR);
}
fclose(fichierResultat);
}

//Main
int main()
{   FILE* Produit;//file of the products
    FILE* MouvementdeProduit;//file of the mouvment
    FILE* ResultatdeMouvedeProduit;//file of the result
    AfficheDeProduitavantMouvement(Produit);
    AfficheDeMouvement(MouvementdeProduit);    ResultatdeMouvement(Produit,MouvementdeProduit,ResultatdeMouvedeProduit);
    AfficheDeProduitApresMouvement(ResultatdeMouvedeProduit);
}
```

Comment: `while(!feof...` is wrong. It tells you the _previous_ read failed, not that the next read will not fail.

Comment: And please indent your code properly. It is very difficult to read now.

Comment: xD i spent almost 5 min trying to indent it tho didn't und what you meant the next read will not fail

Comment: `if(fwrite!=0)` asks whether the `fwrite` function has an address.

Comment: Lookup `feof` in the manual.

Comment: `FILE* fichierMouvment` as an argument is strange. You use it only local, so make it a local variable.

Comment: i've replaced the feof by while (fread(....)) it seems it only write only the first product

Comment: Time for you to take a debugger and step through the program.

Comment: that's what i am doing now actually i'v been almost 3 hours trying to solve it xD thanks for help anyway <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code, some of which I addressed in the comments. I will/did not identify all problems. I will just point you to the problem you are asking about.

The problem is that you skip a lot of records in the input file, so before processing the next product you must rewind the input file:

```
    while(fread(&P,sizeof(P),1,ficheierProduit))
    {
        // You now have a product.
        // Now collect its stock.
        R.StockR= 0;
        *R.NomPr= '\0';
        while(fread(&M,sizeof(M),1,fichierMouvment))
        {
            if(strcmp(P.NomP,M.MouveP)==0){
               strcpy(R.NomPr,P.NomP);
               R.StockR=P.StockP+(M.MouveAp-M.MouveV);
            }
        }
        if (*R.NomPr!='\0') fwrite(&R,sizeof(R),1,fichierResultat);
        // You have now possibly skipped lots of products.
        // So you must rewind the file.
        fseek(fichierMouvment,0, SEEK_SET);
    }
```

Comment: can you explain this line:

Comment: if (*R.NomPr!='\0') fwrite(&R,sizeof(R),1,fichierResultat);

Comment: It tests that the product was found in `fichierMouvment`

Comment: Thank you Mate <3 for real !